# Using MySQL JSON array field to join on a table in knex

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, knex.js

i have two tables slots and bookings. In bookings table i have slots column stored as json array (as shown in figure)

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I need to to get, each slots data when i fetch bookings data.

slots table:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

code i tried:

```
var items = await knex.select().from('bookings').
    innerJoin('rooms', 'bookings.roomId', 'rooms.id').
    innerJoin('users', 'bookings.userId', 'users.id').
    join('slots', 'bookings.slots', 'slots.id').// this is not wokring
    where("date",req.query.date).orderBy("bookings.created_at","desc").
    limit(req.query.lim).offset(req.query.off).options({nestTables: true})
```

It outputs zero rows
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUDcd.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKmCA.png

Comment: Please can you share your simple data as text not image

Comment: Full texts
 id  name  start_time  end_time  roomId  enabled  sortpos  created_at  updated_at  
 hm  1000-01-01 10:23:28  1000-01-01 11:23:28  8  1  NULL  2023-02-25 17:05:22  NULL
 10  test 1000-01-01 17:02:28  1000-01-01 21:02:28  7  1  NULL  2023-02-25 16:39:56  NULL
 9  foo  1000-01-01 16:57:28  1000-01-01 20:57:28  7  1  NULL  2023-02-25 16:36:16  NULL